# was/is a great invention of

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

Which tense should be used in the following? If both are okay, what's the difference in their use?

> The light bulb was/is a great invention of Thomas Edison.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/is-or-was-written-by) at EL&U